# How to identify list of variables_x from url in PHP, using one parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, parameters

I have a members site where users are given up to 7 web page templates to display their products on. Each template has the same field names, differentiated by _1, _2... _7 at the end of each.

For example:

```
// Template 1 would have the following list of variables
product_name_1
product_descript_1
product_color_1
product_price_1

// Template 2 would have the following list of variables
product_name_2
product_descript_2
product_color_2
product_price_2

// through Template 7
```

I am able to display any variables for a specific user within a web page, by use of a query string identifying their user_id in the url, ie

```
http://domain.com/folder/page.php?id=78
```

I then $_Get any variable by simply identifying it in the PHP file, ie

```
$product_name_1
$product_descript_1
$product_color_1
$product_price_1
```

My problem is that the url must identify WHICH template, since each template identifies a specific product, ie _1, _2, ..._7. How do I use a parameter in the url, such as

```
http://domain.com/folder/page.php?id=78&parameter=_7
```

...to identify all variables ending with _7, which would appear in the web page? The parameter used in the url would identify the variables to be used in the web page, whether _1, _2, etc.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the various answers with only partial success, ie "`Array_x`" is displayed when using any particular variable along with the suggested code. There may be a conflict with the rest of the code I'm using in page.php, as follows:

```
$db_connection = new mysqli("", "", "");
if ($db_connection->connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$id = $_GET['id']; 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);

$prop_address=array(
"_1"=>"prop_address_1",
"_2"=>"prop_address_2",
"_3"=>"prop_address_3"
//Through to Temp 7
);

$prop_address{$_GET['parameter']}=$row->prop_address;

    echo " $prop_address{$_GET['parameter']} ";
```

"Array_x" displays (where x=1, 2, 3, etc is used as the parameter in url, ie http://domain.com/page.php?id=72&parameter=1), instead of the actual value held in the database table for `$product_name{$_GET['parameter']}`. For some reason, the code is not picking up the value of the variable from the database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get any of the answers given to work. I found an example given by a user for php variable variables in the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and found it to work. I incorporated it into my code as follows:

```
  $id = $_GET['id']; 
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);

  for( $i = 1; $i < 8; $i++ )
  {
  $product_name[$_GET['parameter']] = "product_name_" . $i; 
  $product_descript[$_GET['parameter']] = "product_descript_" . $i; 
  $product_color[$_GET['parameter']] = "product_color_" . $i; 
  $product_price[$_GET['parameter']] = "product_price_" . $i; 
  }
  ${$product_name[1]}  = "$row->product_name_1"; 
  ${$product_name[2]}  = "$row->product_name_2"; 
  ${$product_name[3]}  = "$row->product_name_3"; 
  ${$product_name[4]}  = "$row->product_name_4"; 
  ${$product_name[5]}  = "$row->product_name_5"; 
  ${$product_name[6]}  = "$row->product_name_6"; 
  ${$product_name[7]}  = "$row->product_name_7"; 

  // List 7 variables and values for each field name

  echo "${$prop_name[$_GET['par']]}";
```

The only problem is that mysql injection is possible with this code. If anyone could suggest a solution, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible to use arrays so...

```
$product_name=array(
    "1"=>"Product name for template 1",
    "2"=>"Product name for template 2"
    //Through to Temp 7
);
echo $product_name[$_GET["parameter"]];
```

You could then do the same for the other variables.

You could fill each array by doing something like:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$product_name[$_GET['parameter']]=$row->product_name;
echo $product_name[$_GET['parameter']];
```

I may be missing something...

Comment: +1 This is the better alternative to what the OP is trying to accomplish. Otherwise, the OP is looking to use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Isn't this based on the use of a parameter for every variable I would need to use in the url query? I have 26 variables per template. I was hoping to get away with using only two parameters in the url, ie `domain.com/page.php?id=72&param=7`. Some of the values hold way too much info to use in a query string, which would make the url more than 255 characters long.

Comment: @user1322707. You can reference every array using `$_GET['parameter']`. So `$product_price[ $_GET['parameter'] ]` if `$product_price` is formatted in the same way.

Comment: Nest the template array. `$arr = array( 1 => array("name" => "Warm Colored", "color" => "#ff0000"), 2 => array("name" => "Cold Colored", "color" => "#0000ff") );` Now, you may access all of the template's variables with a single parameter from the URL. For example, `$arr[2]['name']`.

Comment: @Bonzo if I understand you correctly, `"Product name for template x"` would need to be a set of predetermined values. This is not the case. The user can fill in any value he wants.

Comment: @user1322707 where are these values stored? If they are in a database then can you use SQL to fill in the values.

Comment: Values are stored in a mysql table. I have **UPDATED** my original post to reflect the rest of the code I'm using in page.php which may be conflicting with your answer given.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting a Parse error, so I changed the brackets to curly brackets, ie `$product_name{$_GET['parameter']};`. But now I'm getting `Array_2' when echoing the variable.

Comment: Try 'print_r($product_name);' What is the output you get?

Comment: `Array ( [_1] => city_1 [_2] => B [_3] => city_3 )`

Comment: I have updated the code I'm using in my original post to reflect your last suggestions. Still getting `Array_x` when using `echo`, and the above output when using your suggested `print_r`

Comment: What does `print_r($product_name{$_GET['parameter']};` return. This should just return city_x...

Comment: I'm using `prop_address` instead of `city` or `product_name` to avoid confusion (made changes to original post). I don't get any output when using your last `print_r` suggestion. When using `print_r($product_name);`, the output I get is `Array ( [_1] => prop_address_1 [_2] => [_3] => prop_address_3 )`

Comment: It appears that when I change the parameter in the url from `_2` to `_1', the output of `print_r($prop_address) changes to `Array ( [_1] => [_2] => prop_address_2 [_3] => prop_address_3 )`. As you can see from the previous output, there is no output shown for the parameter used in the url.

Comment: I don't know why that is happening. It should show all of them, not just those that are not the url. What about `$product_name[]=$row->product_name;` to add each one instead, What does that do?

Comment: Doesn't help. But what I noticed is when using `&parameter=2` in the url instead of `&parameter=_2` the output of `print_r($prop_address)` returns a value for each of the 3 stated values assigned in the array. I still get `Array1` in my echo instead of `Array_1`

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['parameter'] = '_2';
$product_name{$_GET['parameter']} = 'string';
echo $product_name_2; // string
```

or

```
$_GET['parameter'] = '_2';
$var = 'product_name'.$_GET['parameter'];
$$var = 'string';
echo $product_name_2; // string
```

Personally, I would use array's for this type of behavior.

**Update:**

Although the above works and tested ok, it is a lot more work than anyone would probably desired.

In lieu of simplicity, I would suggest the approach via array's.

```
$templates = array(2 => array(
        'product_name' => "value",
        'product_descript' => "value",
        'product_color' => "value",
        'product_price' => "value",
    );

foreach($templates[substr($_GET['parameter'],1)] as $var => $val){
    $variable = $var.$_GET['parameter'];
    $$variable = $val;
}
```

The above is backwards compatible, it uses substr to remove the leading _ from your parameter.

Comment: I have 26 variables within each 7 templates. From what I gather of your code, I would need to list your top two lines of code for each parameter (`_1, _2, _3, etc`) with each of 26 variables below it, ie ('$product_name{$_GET['parameter']} = 'string'; $product_price{$_GET['parameter']} = 'string'; etc...`), correct?

Comment: I have **UPDATED** my original post to reflect the rest of the code I'm using in page.php which may be conflicting with your answer given.